# I want to adjust a date for summer/winter time and time zone when insterting it into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, utc

I have a date and time variable in TABLE_A that is in GMT. I want to insert this date and time into TABLE_B, but I want the insterted value to be adjusted for time zone and summer/winter time.
That is:

```
 INSERT into TABLE_A (ADJUSTED_DATE_AND_TIME)

 SELECT GMT_DATE_AND_TIME [Perform proper adjustments here..?]

 FROM TABLE_A
```

Can I do this? In that case, how do I write ?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply convert the GMT/UTC time. However, you have to take the full region name of your time zone.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2014-06-10 12:00:00 +00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich' AS summer FROM dual;

SUMMER                                 
---------------------------------------
10.06.2014 14:00:00.000000000 +02:00   


SELECT TIMESTAMP '2014-12-10 12:00:00 +00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich' AS winter FROM dual;

WINTER                                 
---------------------------------------
10.12.2014 13:00:00.000000000 +01:00
```

Since your source value is data type `DATE` you have to do following steps.

1. Cast `DATE` to `TIMESTAMP`
2. Set Time zone of the value using `FROM_TZ`
3. Convert the value to new time zone using `AT TIME ZONE '...'`
4. Cast the value to `DATE`

Written in a single statement it is

```
select 
CAST(FROM_TZ(CAST(sy_sttime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich' AS DATE)
from sy_request
```

or a bit less clear

```
select
CAST((CAST(sy_sttime AS TIMESTAMP) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Zurich' AS DATE)
from sy_request
```

Comment: Danke sehr for your rapid reply!
However, I get an error: ORA-30084: invalid data type for datetime primary with time zone modifier.

Do you know how I can prevent that?

Comment: What is the data type of column `GMT_DATE_AND_TIME`? Is it a `DATE`? In this case you first have to make a CAST to 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE'.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what data type GMT_DATE_AND_TIME was, but  the cast worked.

select cast (sy_sttime as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'Europe/Zurich', sy_sttime from sy_request

creates these records:
CAST
2014-11-10 20:01:08.000000 +01:00

SY_STTIME
11/10/2014 8:01:08 PM

Can I get the "cast-value" to go directly to the format "11/10/2014 9:01:08 PM" and with the time zone added to the timestamp?

Comment: You get the data type of your column by command `DESC sy_request;`. You can display it at any format using `TO_CHAR` function. See [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) documentation. But **do not** insert the formated string into your date column!

Comment: Then the data type is DATE.

So I guess what I want to do is take a field formatted as DATE, format it into TIMESTAMP, add the time zone,and then format it back to DATE? Am I right? Like:

select to_date(cast(sy_sttime as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'Europe/Zurich'), sy_sttime from sy_request

That doesn't really work. I guess I'm missing something here...

Comment: A date does not have any format, it is stored as in internal value inside the database or memory. Just the **displayed** output has a format. Please see my new answer for your question.